# Angular 2 with 508 accessability

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility

Anyone knows anything about, how to implement **accessibility** in **Angular 2 with Typescript**?

Angular 2 has **Accessibility** (*ARIA-enabled*) feature, but I didn't find any kind of samples/examples, I searched a lot but didn't find anything. Does anyone know how to implement it?

Comment: What is 508 in this context?

Comment: its a 508 accessibility standard.

Comment: Could you add a link to it?

Comment: it explains what exactly 508 accessibility standards are: 

[link] https://www.access-board.gov/guidelines-and-standards/communications-and-it/about-the-section-508-standards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **use all aria attributes** by using **attribute binding:**

```
<!-- create and set an aria attribute for assistive technology -->
<button [attr.aria-label]="actionName">{{actionName}} with Aria</button>
```

---

For example you can use the aria role attribute on a *div* container as shown below:

```
<div [attr.role]="ariaRole">
```

`[attr.role]` binds the role attribute to the result of expression ariaRole.

---

You can find all available aria-attributes [here](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/aria/aria.html).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to muetzerich, I found that the following works for me for setting an aria property like **aria-hidden** with the value in the variable, "detailsHidden"

```
 <div [attr.aria-hidden]="detailsHidden">
```

Here's [Angular2 docs with info on using Aria](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#attribute-class-and-style-bindings).

Here's a [plunker with an example](https://plnkr.co/edit/iFfaDdmkbwnakG1czWyU).

Comment: nice, it is very helpful property.

Comment: Can you provide example of aria property?

Comment: @Darshita are you looking for a list of aria properties?  Here's the W3C documentation on Aria.  Section 3 is a list of allowed Aria roles, states, and properties: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/

Comment: @nkimmet, Thnks . But I m looking for example of aria properties in angular2.

Comment: @Darshita aria-hidden is used as an example in my answer.  Another example would be <input type="text" name="FirstName" [attr.aria-disabled]="FirstNameDisabled"></input>  and then somewhere in the typescript you might set it as true or false like so: FirstNameDisabled = true;  Another example would be <div [attr.aria-label]="mylabel"></div> and then in the typescript somewhere mylabel= "This field needs a dynamic label for aria for some reason";  Does that help?

Comment: @nkimmet. I have tried like , <input type="text" [attr.aria-label]="mylabel"/> and in typescript file mylabel = "This is a label" . But it is not working.

Comment: @Darshita take a look at this example I made. I'm using aria-label on a button and aria-hidden on a div.  When you click the button it changes the aria-label on the button.  In google "inspect" the button and you can see that aria-label is applied: https://plnkr.co/edit/iFfaDdmkbwnakG1czWyU

Comment: @nkimmet, Thanks.